# Grid checkbox get all checked value

Tags: extjs

I have a grid with a check box, and every time I checked 3(three) data's , it doesn't show all the id's instead it only show the 1st data i clicked and display it 3times..

here is my code

```
{
    header: '',
    width: 23,
    dataIndex: 'id_product',
    renderer: function(chck, value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView) {
        return '<input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value="'+chck+'">';

    },

        listeners: {
            click: function(){
                var check = document.getElementsByName('check[]');
                var checkLength = check.length;

                for(var i=0; i < checkLength; i++){       
                    if(check[i].checked){

                     console.log(check[i].value); 
                     break;
                       var store = this.getStore('BP4.sub.ProductPricing.store.PriceListStore');
                       var SKU = store.getAt(i).get('id_product');
                       console.log(SKU);
                    }

                }

            }
        }

}
```

it displays something like this when I clicked 3 data's , it only display and repeat the 1st data id that I clicked,

*--
1 1 1
--*
but I need an output like this

*--
1 2 3
--*

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
var check = document.getElementsByName('check[]');
```

to

```
var check = this;
```

add Class:

```
<input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value="'+chck+'">
```

to:

```
<input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value="'+chck+'" class="cb">
```

then add a listener:

```
Ext.get('cb').on('click', function(e, t){
      t = Ext.get(t);
      console.log(t);
}
```

Comment: try console.log(check); ans post the results

Comment: it shows something like this  [input,input,input] and display all the id of all the data in the grid.

Comment: nope, not yet; because I only click single data but it shows/display all the id.

Comment: are you generating the checkboxes on onReady?